# .NET MVC application into an N Tier application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, model-view-controller, architecture, asp.net-core

In either .NET MVC 5 or a .NET Core MVC application, is it possible to split your Models into a Data Transport Layer, your business logic into a Business Logic Layer and your Db Contexts into a Data Access Layer? I essentially would want the main project to really only have controllers that call to the BLL, and display the results in the view. That way there is portability with my application if I wanted to exchange the main project, which is essentially just a presentation layer.

I know I am going to be needing this kind of architecture as I am building an application that will share a lot of the same business logic between the two applications. What ways can I still get access to helpful features like scaffolding a model into views/controller, and still maintain that portability? Is there a way to do such a thing?

Please note, that this project may be on a short budget, so it is pretty essential to be able to maintain the scaffolding tooling.

Comment: i do this architecturally in one of my solutions. I have a seperate project currenlty WCF project for web services (that implements the repoistory pattern) but you could do this with a class library. I always operate in the boundaries of if I develop another client such as a phone app would all the logic be avilable to the new client. If not then the logic has "seeped" into the wrong project.

Comment: What do you use for a presentation layer?

Comment: MVC 5. With its own view models. We have a service reference and then map from the businss models to the view models. The view models have validation on them but anything to do business logic the domain logic connects back to the service reference to ensure it would be the same for any othe clients such as a phone app

Comment: Now does this approach allow you to scaffold from a model? I guess in your case it would be the View Models?

Comment: correct. This leads to really thin controller actions (which is good). We unit test the actions and models as they have "view/input" logic and validation in them (rightly or wrongly). Main logic is then tested in the WCF project. This also allows multiple people to contribute and makes interface design better IMO. (WCF/web services is irrelvant really. Its about the doing correct sepeartion of concerns)

Comment: Can you give like a more in depth example, preferably with code so I can mark it as the answer?

Comment: it will have to be tomorrow when i have VS cheers

Comment: Will do. Please come back.

Comment: Scaffolding (of mvc views) is of limited use for you as it only works with DbContext oob (maybe there are extensions to add this too regular viewmodels, i dunno), when you abstract the logic, because you won't use your persistence models in the presentation layer (it would cause a violation of the layer separation and any change to the persistence model breaks your other layers) and you won't use your db context in your controllers as this leaks your persistence infrastructure into domain/business and presentation layer

Comment: Scaffold is only useful if you have mainly CRUD operations and can directly work w/ the DbContext, but then you loose much of business logic validation stuff and abstraction. Also, if you are on limited budget, n-layer seems the wrong approach as it needs more initial work architecture and abstractions for a better maintainability later on. Best you look for a different customer or ask for a higher budget if you want to do it right. Good software can't be developed on low budgets